# How to format code in a paragraph like on Stackoverflow

Tags: reactjs

I made myself a blog with React and Go in which I can create an article that stores the title, subtitle and content in a database.
It's a coding block, so I want to format code like on Stackoverflow with the three backticks. How can I achieve that on the frontend it recognizes the backticks and formats the text differently?

Comment: You will need a markdown parser.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Markdown code highlighter like this one for example :

https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown

You can highlight code with plugins:
https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown#use-custom-components-syntax-highlight

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import {Prism as SyntaxHighlighter} from 'react-syntax-highlighter'
import {dark} from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism'

// Did you know you can use tildes instead of backticks for code in markdown? ✨
const markdown = `Here is some JavaScript code;`

ReactDom.render(
  <ReactMarkdown
    children={markdown}
    components={{
      code({node, inline, className, children, ...props}) {
        const match = /language-(\w+)/.exec(className || '')
        return !inline && match ? (
          <SyntaxHighlighter
            children={String(children).replace(/\n$/, '')}
            style={dark}
            language={match[1]}
            PreTag="div"
            {...props}
          />
        ) : (
          <code className={className} {...props}>
            {children}
          </code>
        )
      }
    }}
  />,
  document.body
)
```